# PlaySound() works for 1 sound, is there a function for more?

Tags: c++, wav, playsound

Tried looking for the answer but all I could find was to
add another library like OpenAL and such. (all I use except `windows.h` is glut)

I wrote a multi thread program to check if it is possible that one thread
will keep playing the main theme and the 2nd one will play the sound effects
but unfortunately it does not work...

Comment: Is playing sound about OpenGL? Anyway let's start with **mixerOpen** Win32 function...

Comment: You can try to use OpenAL.

Comment: You can try `SND_ASYNC` parameter for `PlaySound` rather than threads.

Comment: I need to do this without other libraries such as OpenAL.
And I do use ASYNC flag, the threads was just a try to see if 
it can play a few sound files simultaneously . it didn't.

Will read about mixerOpen, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the MCI library?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd742874(v=vs.85).aspx

Here's how I do it:

```
mciSendString(L"open ../mp3/announce_start.mp3 alias announce", 0, 0, 0 );
mciSendString(L"play announce wait", 0, 0, 0 );
```

If you want your sound file to repeat, try

```
mciSendString(L"play announce repeat wait", 0, 0, 0 );
```

Comment: After trying a few codes myself (still hardly understand the syntax)
I've found a few bits of code here and there and collected them to
the following : ( not working - so what is left to add? )
thanks

`TCHAR achCommandBuff[128];
  int result;
  MCIERROR err;
  LPTSTR lpstrAlias=LPTSTR("music.wav");
  // Form the command string.
  result = swprintf_s(
   achCommandBuff, 
   TEXT("play %s"), 
   lpstrAlias); 


  err = mciSendString(achCommandBuff, NULL, 0, NULL);
`

Comment: I cannot make out the code squished into your comment.  It look like maybe you forgot to open your sound file.

Comment: Thanks, it works like charm ( needed to change a few things
so it would work as I want - but great! )
Only left to figure out if there is a loop command to be added.
so far by my findings there is no command similar to repeat
or replay .
but since its on PlaySound I guess there must be one out there.
thanks again :)

Comment: Thanks again , I tried something like that it didnt work
so I had to use SEEK to start every now and then for it to work
:)